# Almacena archivos repetidos en la base de datos, laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Buenos Días tengo un método en el cual yo registro en una tabla en mySQL, pero al subir un archivo con dos usuarios este me sube dos archivos por usuario, y si subo dos archivos a dos usuarios me lo duplica haciéndolo cuatro.

```
public function store(Request $request){     
$machote = $request->input('machote');
      if($machote == 'SI'){
        $plan = $request->input('plantillas');
        $guardado = Plantillas::find($plan);
        $guardado->description = $request->input('editor1');
        $guardado->save();
      }
      $cliens =  $request->input('idclientes');
      $link = $request->input('adjunto');
      $gmail = $request->input('Emails');
      if($cliens != null && $link != null){
      foreach ($cliens as $clien[0+1]) {
        foreach ($link as $key[0+1]) {
        foreach ($gmail as $e_mail[0+1]) {


        $anno = date('Y');
        $fecha = date('M');
        $description = $request->input('editor1');
        $grupos = $request->input('grupos');
        $idgrupo = $request->input('idgrupo');
        $texto = $request->input('plantillas');
        $titulo = $request->input('subject');
        $calendario = $request->input('calendario');
        $id_boletin = $request->input('idarchivo');
        $clients = $request->input('conecta');
        $tablaboletins = $request->input('tablaboletin');
        $tablaboletin = new Boletin();
        $conecta = new Historica();
        foreach($e_mail as $emails){
        foreach ($clien as $cliente_id) {
           foreach ($key as $lnk) {  
            $conecta->titulo = $titulo;
            $conecta->anno = $anno;
            switch ($texto) {
            case '1':

          $conecta->texto ='
          No hay cambios
          ';
          break;
        case '2':
          $conecta->texto = '
          No hay cambios requisitos pero sí informacion de interes
           ' ;
          break;

        case '3':
           $conecta->texto =  
            '
         Sí hay nuevos requisitos legales
           ';
          break;
      }
            switch ($fecha) {
              case 'Jan':
                $conecta->fecha = '0';
                break;
              case 'Feb':
                  $conecta->fecha = '1';
                   break;
                case 'Mar':
                   $conecta->fecha = '2';
                   break;
                case 'Apr':
                   $conecta->fecha = '3';
                   break;
                case 'May':
                  $conecta->fecha = '4';
                   break;
                case 'Jun':
                   $conecta->fecha = '5';
                   break;
                case 'Jul':
                   $conecta->fecha = '6';
                   break;
                case 'Ago':
                   $conecta->fecha = '7';
                   break;
                case 'Sep':
                   $conecta->fecha = '8';
                   break;
                case 'Oct':
                   $conecta->fecha = '9';
                   break;
                case 'Nov':
                   $conecta->fecha = '10';
                   break;
                case 'Dec':
                   $conecta->fecha = '11';
                   break;
            } 
              $tablaboletin->id_files_boletin = $id_boletin;
              $tablaboletin->id_grupo = $idgrupo;
              $tablaboletin->fecha = $calendario;
              $conecta->firma = $description;
              $conecta->grupo = $grupos;
              $conecta->idgrupo = $idgrupo;
              $conecta->emails = $emails;
              $conecta->link = $lnk;
              $conecta->calendario = $calendario;
              $conecta->id_boletin = $id_boletin;
              $conecta->cliente_id = $cliente_id;
              $conecta->save();
              $tablaboletin->save();
            }
          }
         }
       }
     }
   }
}
```

tablaboletin es solo otra tabla para que funcione de historico. la tabla a la que va es la que dice `conecta->save`

les voy a mostrar como es que me queda un registro en la tabla por medio de una imagen. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si pueden ver en amarillo es el usuario en este caso solo mande un archivo, pero duplico y se guardo dos veces.

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que hay seis (6) foreach anidados, sin duda alguna el error está en alguno de ellos, pero el código está un poco desorganizado y es muy largo además para revisarlo (por mi parte).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
      $machote = $request->input('machote');

      if($machote == 'SI'){
        $plan = $request->input('plantillas');
        $guardado = Plantillas::find($plan);
        $guardado->description = $request->input('editor1');
        $guardado->save();
      }

      $cliens =  $request->input('idclientes');
      $link = $request->input('adjunto');
      $gmail = $request->input('Emails');

      if($cliens != null && $link != null){

        foreach ($cliens as $clien[0+1]) {
          foreach ($link as $key[0+1]) {
            foreach ($gmail as $e_mail[0+1]) {
              $anno = date('Y');
              $fecha = date('M');
              $description = $request->input('editor1');
              $grupos = $request->input('grupos');
              $idgrupo = $request->input('idgrupo');
              $texto = $request->input('plantillas');
              $titulo = $request->input('subject');
              $calendario = $request->input('calendario');
              $id_boletin = $request->input('idarchivo');
              $clients = $request->input('conecta');
              $tablaboletins = $request->input('tablaboletin');
              $tablaboletin = new Boletin();
              $conecta = new Historica();

              foreach($e_mail as $emails){
                foreach ($clien as $cliente_id) {
                  foreach ($key as $lnk) {
                    $conecta->titulo = $titulo;
                    $conecta->anno = $anno;

                    switch ($texto) {
                      case '1':
                      $conecta->texto ='No hay cambios';
                      break;

                      case '2':
                      $conecta->texto = 'No hay cambios requisitos pero sí informacion de interes' ;
                      break;

                      case '3':
                      $conecta->texto ='Sí hay nuevos requisitos legales';
                      break;
                    }

                    switch ($fecha) {
                      case 'Jan':
                      $conecta->fecha = '0';
                      break;

                      case 'Feb':
                      $conecta->fecha = '1';
                      break;

                       case 'Mar':
                       $conecta->fecha = '2';
                       break;

                       case 'Apr':
                       $conecta->fecha = '3';
                       break;

                       case 'May':
                      $conecta->fecha = '4';
                       break;

                       case 'Jun':
                       $conecta->fecha = '5';
                       break;

                       case 'Jul':
                       $conecta->fecha = '6';
                       break;

                       case 'Ago':
                       $conecta->fecha = '7';
                       break;

                       case 'Sep':
                       $conecta->fecha = '8';
                       break;

                       case 'Oct':
                       $conecta->fecha = '9';
                       break;

                       case 'Nov':
                       $conecta->fecha = '10';
                       break;

                       case 'Dec':
                       $conecta->fecha = '11';
                       break;
                     }

                     $tablaboletin->id_files_boletin = $id_boletin;
                     $tablaboletin->id_grupo = $idgrupo;
                     $tablaboletin->fecha = $calendario;
                     $conecta->firma = $description;
                     $conecta->grupo = $grupos;
                     $conecta->idgrupo = $idgrupo;
                     $conecta->emails = $emails;
                     $conecta->link = $lnk;
                     $conecta->calendario = $calendario;
                     $conecta->id_boletin = $id_boletin;
                     $conecta->cliente_id = $cliente_id;
                     $conecta->save();
                     $tablaboletin->save();
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    ?>
```

Me tomé la libertad de organizar un poco el código. Faltaba una llave de cierre, puedes comprobar si era el causante del problema.

Comment: O sea que era un simple error tipográfico.